# Spring - validate that all message resources are well configured

Tags: java, spring, jsp

We need to add some code to be executed on application load in order to validate that all the messages.properties elements are well defined for all languages.
Is this possible?

Steps: dynamically read on application load all the spring message codes from JSP or java classes then pass through all message resources properties files and validate that nothing is missing from them.

Comment: Use "ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"

Comment: i am already using this to read properties in the application, but how can this help to achieve the validation i am willing to add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up doing this manually but without using any library. 
**Steps:**

- have all the keys used in Java classes or JSP defined in a constant file
- Read them using Java .class properties:

  ```
   Field[] fields = Constants.class.getFields();
   String filed[i].get(Constants.class);
  ```
- Read all messageResources.properties file names from the project using:

  ```
     String pathToThisClass = MessageResourcesValidator.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocatin().getPath();
     File filePath = new File(pathToThisClass);
     String[] list = filePath.list(new DirFilter("(messages).*\\.(properties)"));
  ```
- DirFilter is a normal class implementing Java's FileNameFilter
- Create a class that read the properties from a file using its file name:

  ```
   public class PropertiesFile{

   private Properties prop;

   public PropertiesFile(String fileName) throws Exception
  {
    init(fileName);
  }

   private void init(String fileName) throws Exception
  {
    prop = new Properties();

    try (InputStream input = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);)
    {
       if(input == null)
       {
          throw new Exception("Enable to load properties file " + fileName);
       }

       prop.load(input);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
       throw new Exception("Error loading properties file " + fileName);
    }
  }

   public List<String> getPropertiesKeysList()
  {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Enumeration<?> e = prop.propertyNames();
    while(e.hasMoreElements())
    {
       result.add((String) e.nextElement());
       // String value = prop.getProperty(key);
    }
    return result;
  }
  }
  ```
- The part that does the comparison should be something as the following code that calls the above methods:

  ```
  List<String> msgResourcesFiles = getMessageResourcesFileNames();
  List<String> codeKeys = getListOfCodeMessageResources();
  PropertiesFile file = null;
  List<String> propKeys = null;
  for(String fileName : msgResourcesFiles)
  {
   file = new PropertiesFile(fileName);
   propKeys = file.getPropertiesKeysList();
   for(String key : codeKeys)
   {
      if(!propKeys.contains(key))
      {
         throw new Exception("Missing key " + key);
      }
   }
  }
  ```

Note: or another workaround would be to compare all message resources files to a default one and this way we minimize the code needed from the above explanation.